# Solve $x^2+y^2+\frac {2xy}{x+y}=1$, $\sqrt {x+y}=x^2-y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, systems-of-equations, radicals, substitution

> Solve the following system :-
>
> $$x^2+y^2+\frac {2xy}{x+y}=1\tag 1$$
>
> $$\sqrt {x+y}=x^2-y \tag 2$$
>
> My try follows:-

I have tried many idea's including squaring the second equation ,  but i have got stuck .
Is there any reference to be more  familiar with these idea's.

Any help  is appreciated 
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
\begin{eqnarray*}
x^2+y^2+\frac{2xy}{x+y}=1 \\
\sqrt{x+y}=x^2-y
\end{eqnarray*}
Now rearrange $(2)$ 
\begin{eqnarray*}
x+y=x^4-2x^2y+y^2 \\
y^2-(2x^2+1)y+x^4-x=0 \\
y= \frac{2x^2+1 \pm (2x+1)}{2}
\end{eqnarray*}
Now taking the positive root $y=x^2+x+1$ and subtituting in $(1)$ ... 
\begin{eqnarray*}
x(x+2)((x+x)^2+(2x+1)^2+1)=0
\end{eqnarray*}
For the negative root $y=x^2-x$ ... 
\begin{eqnarray*}
x^2(x+1)(x-1)((x-1)^2+2)=0
\end{eqnarray*}
We shall reject the solution $(0,0)$ as it causes division by zero in equation $(1)$.
So to summarise $\color{red}{(-2,3),(-1,2),(0,1),(1,-1)}$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\sqrt{x+y}=t$.

Hence, $y=t^2-x$ and $t=x^2-y=x^2-t^2+x$, which says
$$t^2+t=x^2+x$$ or
$$(t-x)(t+x+1)=0.$$
1. $t=x$.

Thus, $\sqrt{x+y}=x$, $y=x^2-x$, where $x\geq0$ and we can substitute it in the first equation.

Since $x+y\neq0$, we obtain $x>0$ and we get
$$x^2+(x^2-x)^2+\frac{2x(x^2-x)}{x^2}=1$$ or
$$x^4-2x^3+2x^2+2x-3=0$$ or
$$x^4-x^3-x^3+x^2+x^2-x+3x-3=0$$ or
$$(x-1)(x^3-x^2+x+3)=0$$
and since $x^3-x^2+x+3>0$ for $x>0$, we get $x=1$;

2. $t=-x-1$.

Thus, $\sqrt{x+y}=-x-1$, where $x\leq-1$.

Hence, $y=x^2+x+1$ and we get
$$x(x^5+4x^4+9x^3+14x^2+10x+4)=0$$ or
$$x^5+4x^4+9x^3+14x^2+10x+4=0$$ or
$$x^5+2x^4+2x^4+4x^3+5x^3+10x^2+4x^2+8x+2x+4=0$$ or
$$(x+2)(x^4+2x^3+5x^2+4x+2)=0$$
and since $x^4+2x^3+5x^2+4x+2>0$, we get $x=-2$ and the answer:
$$\{(1,0),(-2,3)\}.$$
Done!

Comment: Dr. Rozenberg, please say, do you write solution with android keyboard? (İn latex)

Comment: @Samedov No! I just learned LaTeX.

Comment: Not written in latex android keyboard? I write in android. This is so hard.